# Firebase App Distribution: Installing test apps from App Tester fails with exception

Tags: android, firebase-app-distribution

After updating to the latest Android 14 update (Jan 5 security update), I can no longer install APKs from App Tester. Nothing else in our build process has changed, we've verified apk signing is correct. Whenever we hit the install button even on builds which we know were previously installing, it spins for a second then returns to the list of versions without installing the APK. In our logcat we see the exception below logged as we attempt to install. Does anyone have a workaround?

See exception below:

`

```
10:02:19.999 ActivityTaskManager      E  Second failure launching com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallInstalling, giving up
                                         android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 576108 bytes
                                            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
                                            at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleTransaction(IApplicationThread.java:1974)
                                            at android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction.schedule(ClientTransaction.java:136)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:47)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:946)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.test(RootWindowContainer.java:3670)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.test(RootWindowContainer.java:3620)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.forAllActivities(ActivityRecord.java:4710)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllActivities(WindowContainer.java:1838)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllActivities(WindowContainer.java:1832)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.accept(RootWindowContainer.java:3658)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.accept(RootWindowContainer.java:3620)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.Task.forAllRootTasks(Task.java:3153)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2219)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2219)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2219)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2219)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2219)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2219)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2212)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.process(RootWindowContainer.java:3636)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.attachApplication(RootWindowContainer.java:1828)
                                            at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService$LocalService.attachApplication(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:6465)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.finishAttachApplicationInner(ActivityManagerService.java:4914)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.finishAttachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:5016)
                                            at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2720)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2763)
                                            at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1358)
                                            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1304)
10:02:20.001 ActivityManager          I  Process com.google.android.packageinstaller (pid 28124) has died: cch+5 CEM
```

We've tried updating App Tester to the latest version, removing/re-adding testers from our group, force-close and restarting App Tester. We expected to continue to be able to install test APKs via App Tester but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this exact error since that update. For more info, I (and my whole QA team) are unable to install ANY of the previous packages on Google Android 14 devices specifically (Samsungs are working fine).

There is another thread from 4 years ago here:
[Using Firebase App Distribution service is resulting in app not installed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128674/using-firebase-app-distribution-service-is-resulting-in-app-not-installed-error)

I followed that conversation but no dice. I am guessing this has to be an issue with Firebase since I can install everything just fine on an older Android device and it only surfaced on that security update.